# How to Create SplitToneRange for SplitToneFilter in Nokia Imaging SDK

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I am a bit confused by the SplitToneRange IList required for SplitToneFilter.

```
SplitToneFilter(IList<SplitToneRange> splitToneRanges)
```

How does one create such ranges? I did the following but I'm not sure if I am going about this correctly.

```
Windows.UI.Color c = new Windows.UI.Color();
c.R = (byte)155;
c.G = (byte)155;
c.B = (byte)155;
SplitToneRange r = new SplitToneRange(20, 80, c);
SplitToneRange r1 = new SplitToneRange(140, 200, c);
```

Is this a correct start? And if so, how might I add this to the SplitToneRange(..).

I try creating an IList

```
IList<SplitToneRange> l = new IList<SplitToneRange>(); //error
```

But I get the following error

> Cannot create an instance of the abstact class or interface
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IList<Nokia.Graphics.Imaging.SplitToneRange>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not create an instance of an interface (in your case IList). This isn't a limitation of the Imaging SDK, it's just how C# works. Just create a normal list:

```
List<SplitToneRange> list = new List<SplitToneRange>();
```

And then add some SplitToneRanges to it:

```
list.Add(new SplitToneRange(20, 80, Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 155, 155, 155)));
list.Add(new SplitToneRange(140, 200, Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255, 30, 80, 200)));

SplitToneFilter filter = new SplitToneFilter(list);
```

The rest of your code looks correct (haven't tried it), but usually you will have different colors for different SplitToneRanges, as in my example. Try experimenting with the values to get the feel for what the SplitToneFilter actually does.

Comment: I had to create the `Windows.UI.Color` as in my original post because it did not accept byte values when being created. But all in all your solution worked. Thanks! Now I just have to find some good values to input to create a good looking filter. Any recommendations, or perhaps links of others' samples?

Comment: @Matthew Well you can cast the values to byte even in the constructor.

Comment: I suppose in WP8's version the constructor takes no arguments.

Comment: @Matthew you are correct. You should use Color.FromArgb method. I updated my sample to reflect this.